# Construction of set $S$ using averages and reciprocals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Denote $S$ to have the following properties:

1. $A\subseteq S$ for some $n\subseteq\mathbb R$.
2. If $a,b\in S$, then $\frac{a+b}2\in S$.
3. If $a\in S$, then $\frac1{2a}\in S$.

Find the smallest possible $S$ given $A$.

I theorized that for $A=\{1\}$ that $S=\mathbb Q\cap\left[\frac12,1\right]$, but I couldn't prove it. However, I got general bounds that if $k\in S$ then $\frac1{2n}\le k\le n$ if $n$ is the largest element in $A$ and $\frac1{2n}$ is at most the smallest element in $A$.

Comment: Your surmise is definitely not correct.  It won't be right if $n \notin \Bbb Q$.

Comment: @RobertShore My surmise was that if our starting number was $1$ then $S=\mathbb Q\cap\left[\frac12,1\right]$, and I'm pretty sure $1\in\mathbb Q$. Of course this wouldn't apply if $n\notin\mathbb Q$, but those were just my observations for $n=1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm $S=\mathbb Q$ does not satisfy property 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture is not quite correct since if the initial element is a positive rational, then $S=\mathbb Q^+$ is a possible answer.  However if we slightly modify the question by saying that we are looking for the *smallest possible* set, then your answer for $n=1$ is correct.

**Theorem**.  Let $S$ be a set which contains $1$ and satisfies properties 2 and 3 of the question.  Then
$$S\supseteq {\mathbb Q}\cap[\tfrac12,1]\ .$$

To prove this we note (with proof left as an exercise) that properties 2 and 3 are equivalent to the single property
$$\hbox{if}\quad a,b\in S\quad\hbox{then}\quad \frac1{a+b}\in S\ .\tag4$$

We shall prove the main theorem by induction on denominators.  Take any rational $\frac pq$ with $\frac12<\frac pq<1$: we may assume strict inequalities since we already know that $\frac12$ and $1$ are in $S$.  Assume that $S$ contains all rationals between $\frac12$ and $1$ with denominators less than $q$.  First consider the case when $q$ is odd:
$$\frac pq=\frac{p}{2t+1}=\frac{1}{\dfrac{t}{p}+\dfrac{t+1}{p}}\ .\tag{$*$}$$
The fractions in the last expression have denominators less than $q$.  Moreover,
$$\eqalign{\frac12<\frac{p}{2t+1}<1\quad
  &\Rightarrow\quad t+\frac12<p<2t+1\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad t<p\le 2t\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad \frac12\le\frac tp<1\ ;\cr}$$
similarly, $\dfrac12<\dfrac{t+1}{p}\le1$.  So $\dfrac tp$ and $\dfrac{t+1}{p}$ are in $S$; applying $(4)$ to the expression $(*)$ shows that $\dfrac pq$ is in $S$.  If $q$ is even then
$$\frac pq=\frac p{2s}=\frac1{\dfrac sp+\dfrac sp}\ ;$$
the rest of the argument is very similar and I leave it to you.